# Responding to DELETE on UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad

Tags: ios, keyboard, decimal

This thing is driving me crazy.   Anyone how to repond to a user pressing the DELETE key on a numeric keypad?   I can't find a delegate method for it and I only see an empty string when shouldChangeCharactersInRange() is called.

Thanks!

Comment: Check the actual range value. if the range of characters is less than the length of the string that might indicate a delete.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out...

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range
                                                replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    if ([string length] == 0)
        return YES;

    NSCharacterSet *nonNumberSet = [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet];
    string = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:nonNumberSet] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    textField.text = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];


return NO;
```

}